# Find the area of the smallest rectangle to contain squares of sizes up to n

Tags: code-golf, packing

This is a sequence question of the usual type, as applied to [OEIS sequence A038666](https://oeis.org/A038666). That is, do either of the following:

- Accept no or any input, and output A038666 until the heat death of the universe.
- Accept a positive integer as input, and output the \$n\$th term of A038666 or its first \$n\$ terms. (If using \$0\$- instead of \$1\$-indexing, then of course you also have to output `1` on `0` input.)

The \$n\$th term of A038666 is the least area among rectangles that contain non-overlapping squares of sizes \$1\times1,2\times2,\dots n\times n\$ if you're using \$1\$-indexing.

#### Example:

The smallest-area rectangle which can contain non-overlapping squares of sizes \$1\times1\$ through \$4\times4\$ has dimensions \$7\times5\$:

```
4 4 4 4 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 2 2 1
x x x x 2 2 x
```

Therefore, \$a(4)=7\times5=35\$ (\$1\$-indexed).

Similarly, the least-area rectangle containing non-overlapping squares of sizes \$1\times1\$ through \$17\times17\$ [has dimensions \$39\times46\$](http://web.archive.org/web/20190218045512/http://www.mathpuzzle.com/17sqrsrect.gif), so \$a(17)=39\times46=1794\$ (\$1\$-indexed).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES6), 172 bytes

*Slower but shorter version suggestion suggested by @JonathanAllan (also saving 4 bytes in the original answer):*

```javascript
f=(n,A,S=(n,c)=>n>=0?c(n)||S(n-1,c):0)=>S(A,w=>(F=(l,n)=>n?S(w-n,x=>S(A/w-n,y=>l.some(([X,Y,W])=>X<x+n&X+W>x&Y<y+n&Y+W>y)?0:F([...l,[x,y,n]],n-1))):A%w<1)([],n))?A:f(n,-~A)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY5BboNADEX3OcUs0sgWZgrLUgY0m1yARUAIKYhA1Yp6qlAVEKFXp6ar//X8LPuj/qmH5v7@9e2zu7Xb1hlgspTt0aBJODFB2gDj45EB@6HAKBCegaXRJHA20BPvYprB6DNN/7Pnvc4m6fXgPluAMqeCLpV4eTx5fMq9SzKdiniWXkifMQ2iM5Ra657KiWbiqiK5h4iRfRrjEKEUgJjaqJPf/F@LW@fuwMqo8FWxitWLhOehWg5KNY4H17e6d29wreG48IpiHhdZxvWKh3X7Aw)

---

## Original answer,  <s>209 183 178</s>  174 bytes

Returns the \$N\$<sup>th</sup> term of the sequence, 1-indexed.

```javascript
f=(n,A,S=(n,c)=>n>=0?c(n)||S(n-1,c):0)=>S(A,w=>A%w?0:(F=(l,n)=>n?S(w-n,x=>S(A/w-n,y=>l.some(([X,Y,W])=>X<x+n&X+W>x&Y<y+n&Y+W>y)?0:F([...l,[x,y,n]],n-1))):1)([],n))?A:f(n,-~A)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY7BboNADETv@Yo9pJEtzBaulAVxyQ9wCAghBVGoGm28VagKiNBfp6anGY@ePb41P83QPj6/vn1279229QaYMsp3adEknJggbYHx@cyB/VDCKJA8h4xGk2QvYxpEcDZgiXc8zWH0maZ/4nW3s0msHty9A6gKKulSC1fEk8enwrsk06mMZ/Gl@Bnl2BkqrbWlaqKZuK5JWhExChEqGRDTLOrlO/83w613D2BlVPimWMUqDEQ9D9VyUKp1PDjbaes@4NrAceEVBT0uso3rFQ/r9gc)

### Commented

#### Helper function

We first define a helper function \$S\$ which invokes a callback function \$c\$ for \$n\$ to \$0\$ (both included) and stops as soon as a call returns a truthy value.

```javascript
S = (n, c) =>               // n = integer, c = callback function
  n >= 0 ?                  // if n is greater than or equal to 0:
    c(n) ||                 //   invoke c with n; stop if it's truthy
    S(n - 1, c)             //   or go on with n - 1 if it's falsy
  :                         // else:
    0                       //   stop recursion and return 0
```

#### Main function

We start with \$A=1\$.

For each pair \$(w,h)\$ such that \$w\times h = A\$, we try to insert all squares of size \$1\times1\$ to \$n\times n\$ (actually starting with the largest one) in the corresponding area, in such a way that they don't overlap with each other.

We keep track of the list of squares with their position \$(X,Y)\$ and their width \$W\$ in \$l[\text{ }]\$.

We either return \$A\$ if a valid arrangement was found, or try again with \$A+1\$.

```javascript
f = ( n,                    // n = input
      A ) =>                // A = candidate area (initially undefined)
S(A, w =>                   // for w = A to w = 0:
  A % w ?                   //   if w is not a divisor of A:
    0                       //     do nothing
  : (                       //   else:
    F = (l, n) =>           //     F = recursive function taking a list l[] and a size n
      n ?                   //       if n is not equal to 0:
        S(w - n, x =>       //         for x = w - n to x = 0
          S(A / w - n, y => //           for y = A / w - n to y = 0:
            l.some(         //             for each square in l[]
            ([X, Y, W]) =>  //             located at (X, Y) and of width W:
              X < x + n &   //               test whether this square is overlapping
              X + W > x &   //               with the new square of width n that we're
              Y < y + n &   //               trying to insert at (x, y)
              Y + W > y     //
            ) ?             //             if some existing square does overlap:
              0             //               abort
            :               //             else:
              F([ ...l,     //               recursive call to F:
                  [x, y, n] //                 append the new square to l[]
                ],          //
                n - 1       //                 and decrement n
              )             //               end of recursive call
          )                 //           end of iteration over y
        )                   //         end of iteration over x
      :                     //       else (n = 0):
        1                   //         success: stop recursion and return 1
    )([], n)                //     initial call to F with an empty list of squares
) ?                         // end of iteration over w; if it was successful:
  A                         //   return A
:                           // else:
  f(n, -~A)                 //   try again with A + 1
```

Comment: Save 6* by not defining `h` and moving the test for `a%w<1` to the tail of the recursion [TIO](https://tio.run/##HY5BboNADEX3OcUs0sgWhsKuosywywVYBISQMiJQtZp6qlAVEKFXp6ar//X8LPvD/tihvb9/fYfsb9229RqYLBV7tKgNGx3nLTA@HgVwmAhMY@EFWBq1gbMGR7yLeQFjyDT9z573OmvjosF/dgB1SRVdGvHKbAr4VAYXM52qbJZeSZ8xj9Mz1FEUOaonmombhuQeIqb2acwShFoAYm7TXn4Lfy1uvb8DK62SV8UqUy8SQYBqOSjVeh686yLn3@Bq4bjwimIeF1nG9YqHdfsD). Of course it's much slower. (* at least - I'm no JavaScript expert!)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks. :) Actually, I wonder if `a%w<1` could be replaced with just `1`. I'll have to double-check that later.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2 (PyPy)](http://pypy.org/), <s>250</s> 236 bytes

-14 bytes thanks to [msh210](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/1976/msh210)'s suggestions.

Outputs the 1-indexed nth term of the sequence.

```python
n=input()
r=range
k=n*-~n*(n-~n)/6
m=k*k
for Q in r(m):
 P={0}
 for X in r(n,0,-1):P|=([x for x in[{(x+a,y+b)for a in r(X)for b in r(X)}for x in r(Q%k-X+1)for y in r(Q/k-X+1)]if not x&P]+[{0}])[0]
 if len(P)>k:m=min(Q%k*(Q/k),m)
print m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7LCoMwEEX3@YrZtGR8oJbShZB@g@4EcWGhj5BmDMGCwdpft1HbzcA998wwxvWPjg6xccbNMwlJ5tVzZFbYlu5XpgQF8YcCTn5icmJaqECxW2ehBElgucacQSHGdGKw4GrDFKVRnGFevAWvh7UZfFOPfAjbyIUXXFC7ydUaLv8w/W2fyp2KqzBbBfdDyYYaeQPqehj2RRPW/oEG67Rh4PHzSrzAs8q10JKWI8GyhpFGZqykHvQ8H78) For n>4, this takes lot of time. I have verified the result up to n=7 locally.

Comment: Would you mind including an explanation of how it works? Also, I imagine you can shave bytes by indenting one space at a time instead of seven (for the second indentation). (In fact, I think maybe the two `for` lines can be on one line, and you only need to indent once.)

Comment: @msh210 the "7 spaces" are in fact a tab, as in Python 2 you can indent first with a space, then with a tab. Putting the two for loops on one line would be invalid syntax unfortunately.

Comment: @msh210 I found a different way to combine those for loops. Those 7 spaces where only on line, thanks for the catch. I will try to write an explanation tomorrow